# Kendo Grid sometimes renders only title or data

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a pretty simple Kendo Grid that displays a list of data with titles and is conditionally editable on a field. This is rendered and attached to the DOM using JQuery in a function that is called in the "show" action of a Kendo View.

The issue is that either the data does not render or the grid column headers don't render every time I load the page. It's always one or the other, the only time it renders properly is if I refire the function that attaches it as I occasionally do when the state of the page changes.

Here's where I attach it to the page:

```
form.find("#approvals").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        { title: "Service", field: "PartDescription" },
        { title: "Component", field: "Component", width: "250px" },
        { title: "Status Last Modified", width: "250px", template: "#= kendo.toString(StatusModifiedDate, 'g') #", },
        { title: "Status", field: "Status", width: "135px", editor: statusDropDownEditor }
    ],
    editable: modifyState,
    edit: function (e) {
        if (e.container.find("input").attr("name") !== "Status") {
            this.closeCell();
        }
    }
});
```

This comes from the function that is fired when the Kendo View is shown.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that either the data does not render or the grid column
>   headers don't render every time I load the page.

Without knowing what "form" is in your js code, try using this to make sure it loads at the 'correct' time. Please feel free to tinker the gridData variable to match your code and preg_replace the fields for your fields.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

</head>
<body id="theBod">
  <div id="approvals"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () { // the dom is ready for jquery parsing 
    var gridData = [{
        "Name": "daya",
        "Role": "Developer",
        "Dept": "Dev",
        "Date": "\/Date(836438400000)\/",
        "Balance": 23
    }, {
        "Name": "siva",
        "Role": "Developer",
        "Dept": "Dev",
        "Date": "\/Date(836438400000)\/",
        "Balance": 23
    }, {
        "Name": "sivadaya",
        "Role": "Developer",
        "Dept": "Dev",
        "Date": "\/Date(836438400000)\/",
        "Balance": 23
    }, {
        "Name": "dayasiva",
        "Role": "Developer",
        "Dept": "Dev",
        "Date": "\/Date(836438400000)\/",
        "Balance": 23
    }];

    var form = $("#theBod");
    var foundForm = $(form).find("#approvals");

    if (typeof (foundForm) != "undefined") {
        // process grid component
        var grid = $(foundForm).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: gridData,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            Name: { type: "string" },
                            Role: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10,
            },
            editable: true,
            sortable: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "Name",
                    title: "Name",
                },
                {
                    field: "Role",
                    title: "TheRole"
                }
            ]
        });

    } else {
        alert('no dom element located');
    }
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added a [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/xufabuc/edit?html,js,output) file for you.

The jsBin was not saved correctly, apologies.

Comment: Form is the view itself, sorry.

Comment: Making it immediately invoked does not help (just tried it). It's not an issue of it not loading, the data comes in most of the time, just when it does it does not have headers. When it does not come in, it has headers without data, but that's rare.

Comment: Do you have a sample json dataset to share with the post?

Comment: Since your updates: this is in line with what I already have - a data source feeding into the Kendo Grid - with the addition of checking if it can find 'approvals' prior to attaching it. Even with the added checking, which does not fail, I have issues with the title not showing up above the columns. Did you change anything other than that that I may have missed?

Comment: @lgh the title should be a string value

Comment: step 1: tackle your datasource. step 2: take your grid, use only one column. step 3: profit